# Grouping values after Unique symbology classification in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, multi-values

I have a layer that I am using the unique values, many fields symbology category for but I have two different values that I would like to have displayed with the same symbol and label for that symbol in the legend.

If I didn't have a legend I would just assign them both the same symbol and not worry about it but with the legend it would end up having the same thing twice on it that way.

Is there a way to make a value in this situation be some thing like -1,* where as long as the first value field is -1 it doesn't matter what the second one is?

Comment: Select both of them, when in the Symbology tab. Right-click --> Group. Then they will get the same symbol and description (works for more than two as well, it will assign the symbol of the one highest up in the list).

Comment: @Martin you should Really make this an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Jordan - Another option is to use convert legend to grpahics, explode legened items, remove one of the duplicates and edit the other

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by @Martin in a comment, the way to do this is by using Group Values.  Here I have selected three values (using Ctrl key to multiple select)   Then, after right clicking, I am choosing to have them appear using a single symbol.

[image]

I can now type whatever Label I want for that grouped value.

[image]